# Unexpected ROW_NUMBER behaviour when OUTPUT through DELETE

Tags: t-sql, window-functions

I would expect `[version]` to be larger than 1 in `#X` below, but it rather seems as if `ROW_NUMBER` is reevaluated on its way into `#X`. Is this the intended behavior and is there any way to prevent it?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #T;
CREATE TABLE #T (id INT, v CHAR(1));
INSERT INTO #T VALUES (1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (2, 'c');
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #X;
SELECT TOP 0 *, 1 AS [version] INTO #X FROM #T;
DELETE t OUTPUT deleted.* INTO #X FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY v) AS [version] FROM #T
) t WHERE t.[version] > 1;
SELECT * FROM #X;
```

Comment: I'd be surprised if there's any *documented* behaviour on this. I don't think you should assume *either* that it'll be re-evaluated or that it will not be.

Comment: You probably should fill `#X` before the deletion instead of filling it with the OUTPUT.

Comment: While filling `#X` before certainly would work, it results in `#T` being scanned twice, which is bad thing considering the number of rows in my actual tables.

Comment: What is wrong, or at least confusing, it that the rows conditioned in the delete are the ones for which `[version] > 1`, but a lot of rows ending up in `#X` have `[version] = 1`.

Comment: A [blog post from 2011](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/piotr_rodak/archive/2011/07/31/output-clause-and-windowing-functions.aspx) that reported similar issue (images missing). It was raised as a bug on the now defunct "Connect" website and later marked as fixed, but we have no real details of what was fixed or in what version. Many indications that it wasn't fixed in the Denali timeframe (2012). What version are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-CU4) (KB4024305) - 13.0.4446.0 (X64)   Jul 16 2017 18:08:49 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Developer Edition (64-bit)

Comment: Good find on that blog post!